What do the $x$ and $y$ axes mean on a chromaticity diagram?
I understand that the chromaticity diagram is a plot of visible wavelength colors. Since the visible wavelengths form a curve on the graph, what do the  $x$ and $y$ axes mean? My thinking could be that they mean hue or saturation, but I can't find anything that approves this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromaticity has some info

In a sense they represent an imaginary color that could stimulate only your red receptors (for x) and only your green receptors (for y).   There is no real light spectrum that can do either perfectly because all real colors will tend to stimulate both.
So the real reds appear at high values of x, and the real greens appear at high values of y.
And since the plane that is shown is usually chosen so that all points are at a fixed luminance, points low in both this "redness" and "greeness", must instead be higher in "blueness".

